# Does QUIC use the TLS 1.3 Exporter Master Secret?

Tags: tls

QUIC is protected by TLS 1.3.  TLS 1.3 generates many keys, to include an **Exporter Master Secret** -- is this the key that is used to start the key generation process within QUIC?

If not that, is there another key from TLS 1.3's Key Schedule which is provided to QUIC?

If not *that*, does QUIC traffic simply traverse *within* a regular TLS 1.3 session, like any other TLS 1.3 SSL VPN or HTTPS session, using the regular TLS 1.3 Session Keys generated from the **Application Traffic Secret**

If not even that.... than in what way does TLS 1.3 protect QUIC?

Comment: rfc9001 Using TLS to Secure QUIC.  Abstract: This document describes how Transport Layer Security (TLS) is used to secure QUIC.
Section 3:  QUIC assumes responsibility for the confidentiality and integrity protection of packets.  For this it uses keys derived from a TLS handshake, but instead of carrying TLS records over QUIC (as with TCP), TLS handshake and alert messages are carried directly over the QUIC transport, which takes over the responsibilities of the TLS record layer.

Comment: @JeanPierre This answers my 3rd question -- thank you.  But the question of *"which keys from TLS 1.3 does QUIC use?"* still remain.